# Computing Moran's I from a ggplot map using R

Tags: r, ggplot2, moran-index

In an effort to detect spatial autocorrelation using Moran's I in some variables, I was wondering how I could go about creating a polygonal shapefile from a ggplot-created map. My data lists multiple years (2010-2017) of variables for the 48 contiguous US states to which I've joined to the 'states' shapefile of the'urbnmapr' R package. However, whenever I try to create a shapefile from the joined data, it describes 'map_data' as a 'SpatialPointsDataFrame' as opposed to 'SpatialPolygon'. This gets in the way of the function 'poly2nb' where try to define the neighbor list ([Reference](https://mgimond.github.io/simple_moransI_example/) I'm using to calculate Moran's I).

I'm just trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong and how I can go about fixing this.

```
> head(df, n = 10)
# A tibble: 10 x 13
# Groups:   YEAR, CENSUS_DIVISION, STATE_FULL, STATE, FIPS, CT_LAT [10]
    YEAR CENSUS_DIVISION STATE_FULL STATE FIPS  CT_LAT CT_LON  GDPr    LI     SD     MM      MA      PA
   <int> <fct>           <fct>      <fct> <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1  2010 PACIFIC         California CA    06      37.1  -120. 55147    18  0.838  3.03   1.52    1.77  
 2  2010 PACIFIC         Oregon     OR    41      44.0  -121. 44043     5  0.206  0.219 -0.486   1.28  
 3  2010 PACIFIC         Washington WA    53      47.4  -121. 56541     5 -0.327  0.507 -0.0230  2.42  
 4  2010 MOUNTAIN        Arizona    AZ    04      34.2  -112. 40183     4  0.603  1.32   1.07    0.173 
 5  2010 MOUNTAIN        Colorado   CO    08      39.0  -106. 52452     3 -0.368  0.566  0.115  -0.535 
 6  2010 MOUNTAIN        Idaho      ID    16      44.3  -115. 36865     4 -0.152 -0.568  1.38    0.0780
 7  2010 MOUNTAIN        Montana    MT    30      47.1  -110. 40924     1 -0.823 -1.14   0.256  -0.215 
 8  2010 MOUNTAIN        Nevada     NV    32      39.3  -117. 47670     4  0.842  2.00  -0.118   0.513 
 9  2010 MOUNTAIN        New Mexico NM    35      34.4  -106. 42141     1  0.846  1.76   0.743   0.269 
10  2010 MOUNTAIN        Utah       UT    49      39.3  -112. 44438    -3 -0.571 -0.285  3.23   -0.223 

> states <- data(urbnmapr::states)
> head(states, n = 10)
# A tibble: 10 x 9
    long   lat order hole  piece group state_fips state_abbv state_name
   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <lgl> <fct> <fct> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     
 1 -88.5  31.9     1 FALSE 1     01.1  01         AL         Alabama   
 2 -88.5  31.9     2 FALSE 1     01.1  01         AL         Alabama   
 3 -88.5  31.9     3 FALSE 1     01.1  01         AL         Alabama   
 4 -88.5  32.0     4 FALSE 1     01.1  01         AL         Alabama   
 5 -88.5  32.0     5 FALSE 1     01.1  01         AL         Alabama   
 6 -88.5  32.1     6 FALSE 1     01.1  01         AL         Alabama   
 7 -88.4  32.2     7 FALSE 1     01.1  01         AL         Alabama   
 8 -88.4  32.2     8 FALSE 1     01.1  01         AL         Alabama   
 9 -88.4  32.2     9 FALSE 1     01.1  01         AL         Alabama   
10 -88.4  32.3    10 FALSE 1     01.1  01         AL         Alabama 

> map_data <- left_join(df, states, by = c("FIPS" = "state_fips"))
> map_data %>%
   ggplot(aes(long, lat, group = group, fill = GDPr)) +
   facet_wrap("YEAR") + 
   geom_polygon(color = NA) +
   coord_map(projection = "albers", lat0 = 39, lat1 = 45) +
   labs(fill = "")
```

[image]
`

```
> WGScoor <- subset(map_data, YEAR == 2010)

> coordinates(WGScoor)=~long+lat

> proj4string(WGScoor)<- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

> LLcoor<-spTransform(WGScoor,CRS("+proj=longlat"))

> raster::shapefile(LLcoor, filename = "Folder/Shapefile.shp", overwrite = T)

> SP2010 <- readOGR("Folder", layer = "Shapefile")
> SP2010
class       : SpatialPointsDataFrame 
features    : 72247 
extent      : -124.7332, -66.94989, 24.51496, 49.38436  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +no_defs 
variables   : 19
names       : YEAR, CENSUS_, STATE_F, STATE, FIPS,...

> poly2nb(SP2010, queen = T)
Error in poly2nb(SP2010, queen = T) : Not a polygon object
```

`

Answer (score 2):

At this point:

```
 > WGScoor <- subset(map_data, YEAR == 2010)
```

`map_data` is a data frame with one point per vertex and a grouping variable, like `piece`, that defines the polygons. You then do:

```
 > coordinates(WGScoor)=~long+lat
```

which turns it into a spatial object, one spatial feature per row, and each row is a point. Its not polygons, because the `sp` package that defines these objects doesn't work with the polygons defined in ggplots "one row per point with a grouping variable" form.

This `urbnmapr` package doesn't appear on CRAN at this time. Does it have objects in `sp` format you can work with? You should be able to find a map of the USA states with matching FIPS codes and state abbreviations from a number of sources. Try the `USABoundaries` package (on CRAN).

Further, I'd suggest working with `sf` class objects instead of either `sp` or the needlessly bloated `ggplot` formats. `sf` objects behave a lot more like data frames when joining, and you can use packages such as `tmap` to make really good maps.

Answer (score 1):

The data in `states <- data(urbnmapr::states)` are not SpatialPolygons - they're just the SpatialPoints info to build the polygons if you wanted to (which apparently ggplot does automatically for you).

Look at the sample data you shared - there are 10 listings just for Alabama. If each row was a polygon, you should just see one row per state. The listings are of spatial points (lat/long) along with the order that they go in if you want use them to build a polygon, which you can do with your preferred spatial package.

Comment: `states` isn't strictly even `SpatialPoints` - its just a dataframe with lat and long columns. And no coordinate system reference. `WGScoor` magically becomes a `SpatialPoints` object when it gets `coordinates(WGScoor)` assigned to it.